# Is $\{0\}$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2 , p)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Associate with $\mathbb{R}^2 $ the euclidean metric and denote  its  by $d$ . Define   on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 $ a  function  $p$  by 
$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, \text{x=y} \\ d(x,0) + d(y,0) ,  x \neq y \end{cases}$$ where  $0 = (0,0)$

Now my question is that

Is $\{0\}$  is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2 , p)$?

My attempt : I thinks  yes because we have  $B(a,r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d(x,0) + d(a,0)  < r\}$ and   $B(0,r)  \subset \{0\}$

Is its true ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: So you are using the $\mathcal{L}_1$ metric. Under any $\mathcal{L}_n$ metric, finite sets are not open.

Comment: $B(a,r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : p(a,x)  < r\}.$ So, in particular, $B(0,r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : p(0,x)  < r\} =  \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d(0,x)  < r\}.$ Clearly, there are other $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ than $0$ that belongs to  $B(0,r),$ such as $x=(0,r/2)$ for example

Comment: @DonThousand Is this not more like the notorious French railway metric? Except that it is not quite that either. Here the train from $x$ to Paris has no intermediate stops.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Perhaps I misread? I shall look again.

Comment: Why do you think B (0,r) $\subset $ {0}?  That's obviously false p((r/3,r/3),(0,0))=2r/3 <r.  So (r/3,r/3) in B (0,r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. because  $B(0,r) = \{ x : d(0,x) < r \}$
is not a subset of $\{0\}$ because $(0,\frac{r}{2})$ in $B(0,r).$

Answer (score 2):

If $\{0\}$ is open, then there exists $r>0$ such that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:p(x,0)<r\}\subseteq \{0\}$, i.e., $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:d(x,0)<r\}\subseteq\{0\}$, which is not possible as $d$ is the Euclidean norm.( For example, $(\frac{r}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{r}{2\sqrt{2}})$ is in $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:d(x,0)<r\}$)